Как вывести записи по ближайшей дате сгруппированные по категориям в MySQL 5.7?
Есть три таблицы: events, events_categories, event_category_joins (связующая). Необходимо вывести записи с ближайшей датой сгруппированные по категориям.
Пример вывода без группировки:

Код с группировкой:
select `events`.`id`,
`events`.`date_public`,
`event_categories`.`id` as `cat_id`,
`event_categories`.`title` as `cat_title`
from `events`
inner join `event_category_joins` on `events`.`id` = `event_category_joins`.`event_id` 
inner join `event_categories` on `event_categories`.`id` = `event_category_joins`.`event_category_id` 
where `events`.`date_public` >= CURDATE()
group by `event_categories`.`id`
order by `events`.`date_public` asc;

Выводит таким образом (не по ближайшей дате, а по наименьшему events.id.):

Пробовал группировать через join, находить наименьшую дату и сравнивать с датой основной таблицы :
select `events`.`id`,
`events`.`date_public`,
`event_categories`.`id` as `cat_id`,
`event_categories`.`title` as `cat_title`
from `events`
inner join `event_category_joins` on `events`.`id` = `event_category_joins`.`event_id` 
inner join `event_categories` on `event_categories`.`id` = `event_category_joins`.`event_category_id` 
inner join (select `events`.`id` as `e_id`, min(`events`.`date_public`) as `min_date_public` 
            from `events` 
            inner join `event_category_joins` on `events`.`id` = `event_category_joins`.`event_id` 
            inner join `event_categories` on `event_categories`.`id` = `event_category_joins`.`event_category_id` 
            where `events`.`date_public` >= CURDATE() 
            group by `event_categories`.`id`) as `events_cat` 
on `events`.`id` = `events_cat`.`e_id`
where `events`.`date_public` = `events_cat`.`min_date_public`
order by `events`.`date_public` asc;

Выводит так:

В идеале нужно, чтобы вывелись записи по следующим id: 101, 102, 106, 109, 110.

Посмотрите пример:
select *
from event_categories ec
inner join (
  select *
    ,row_number()over(partition by ecj.event_category_id order by e.date_public) rn
  from events e
  inner join event_category_joins ecj on ecj.event_id=e.id
  where e.date_public>curdate()
  ) oe on oe.event_category_id=ec.id
where rn=1




id
title
id
date_public
event_id
event_category_id
rn




1
Вебинар
106
2024-04-24
106
1
1


2
Онлайн курс
104
2024-09-19
104
2
1


3
Видеокурс
110
2024-04-10
110
3
1


5
Стажировка
102
2024-07-09
102
5
1


6
Практикум
101
2024-05-16
101
6
1



